# How to add values to a list at runtime in java

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to make my code flexible but I am not sure if it is possible.

I have the following objects:

```
        Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle();
        v1.setColor("red");
        v1.setPriority(Integer.valueOf(0));
        v1.setModel("sport");

        Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle();
        v2.setColor("blue");
        v2.setPriority(Integer.valueOf(0));
        v2.setModel("sedan");

        Vehicle v3 = new Vehicle();
        v3.setColor("red");
        v3.setPriority(Integer.valueOf(1));
        v3.setModel("sport");

        Vehicle v4 = new Vehicle();
        v4.setColor("blue");
        v4.setPriority(Integer.valueOf(1));
        v4.setModel("sedan");

        Vehicle v5 = new Vehicle();
        v5.setColor("black");
        v5.setPriority(Integer.valueOf(2));
        v5.setModel("hashback");
```

I want to filter those ones who are repeated by `n` properties and taking into account the priority. For example:

```
private static void checkVehicle2(List<Vehicle> current, List<Vehicle> previous)
    {
        Map<List<String>, Vehicle> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<Vehicle> flat = flatMap(current, previous); //joins current and previous
        List<Vehicle> sort = sortByPriority(flat); //descent order[3,2,1,0]

        for(int index = 0; index < sort.size(); index++)
        {
            List<String> key = new ArrayList<>();
            key.add(sort.get(index).getColor());
            key.add(sort.get(index).getModel());
            map.put(key, sort.get(index));
        }
    }
```

The method `checkVehicle2` does what I want (filters taking color and model and priority). 
**Answer:**
 `{[black, hashback]=Vehicle [color=black, model=hashback, year=null, priority=2], [red, sport]=Vehicle [color=red, model=sport, year=null, priority=0], [blue, sedan]=Vehicle [color=blue, model=sedan, year=null, priority=0]}`

The point is that is not flexible. I would like to be open to the number of properties (1, 2 and etc). Do you have any idea?

Comment: Write a `getKey` method in `Vehicle`.

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to do cause your method is void. Also looking on params function flatMap shouldn't be called flatMap. It's not flattening anything. To have an answer on this question please specify what is current, previous and what flatMap function does?

Comment: I added some comments to the code. Indeed it is flatennijg, why do you say it's not? current and previous as the type says are two list of Vehicle